# Stop jQuery form validation resetting typeahead.js input field that is populated by other JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validator to require a text input field before submit. The form works as follows:

1. On page load, a JavaScript function attempts geolocation.
2. When geolocation succeeds, the input field is populated (except if the user has already filled it).

I'm seeing a problem when a user clicks submit before geolocation succeeds and before they've entered anything in the input field. The form correctly fails to validate, but when geolocation succeeds and successfully populates the input field (and the form is revalidated successfully), if the user then clicks submit, the input field is reset to blank and fails validation.

I can't see what is causing the field to be reset. Is it jQuery validator? How can I stop it from being reset on being re-submit?

Here's the relevant code:

The form (styling removed):

```
<form action='/find' id='search-form' method='post' role='form'>
  <select id='what' name='what'>
    <option>...</option>
  </select>
  <input id='where' name='where' type='text'>
  <button id='search-form-submit' type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
```

The jQuery code:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  success: "valid"
});
$('#search-form').validate({
  rules: {
    where: {
       required: true
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
     $(element).addClass('error');
  },
  success: function(element) {
    $(element).removeClass('error');
  },
  errorPlacement: function(){
   return false;
  }
});
```

On geolocation success, this executes:

```
if (!document.getElementById('where').value) { // if user hasn't typed anything yet...
  document.getElementById('where').value = postcode; // populate with the geolocated postcode
  var validator = $('#search-form').validate();
  validator.element("#where"); // revalidate the form field (this works)
}
```

Comment: There must be something missing from your code.  Show us a _complete_ concise example.  See:  http://sscce.org

Comment: @Sparky you're right, the fault lied in my usage of typeahead.js in the same input field. Thanks for your help and please forgive my inexperience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was being caused by typeahead.js, which I didn't see as being related (although now it's entirely obvious).

The solution seems to be to set the typeahead.js query when updating the input field value, in this case:

```
$('#where').typeahead('setQuery', postcode);
```

I bashed my head against this for a while, so I hope someone else finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote Title:**

> *"Stop jQuery form validation resetting typeahead.js input field that is populated by other JavaScript"*

The premise of the question is flawed.  **There is nothing in the jQuery Validate plugin that can alter the value of your data input fields.**  That's up to the user or somewhere else in your code.

**Quote OP:**

> *"I can't see what is causing the field to be reset."*

Neither can I.  Perhaps it's not in the code you've provided.   Otherwise, this is the only single thing you've shown that will alter the value of an input field...

```
document.getElementById('where').value = postcode;
```

---

---

**Side-notes:**

1) The `unhighlight` callback function is the compliment to the `highlight` function, not `success`.  The `success` callback is typically used when you want to manipulate the normally hidden error `label` on a "valid" field, like for showing a check-mark.

Your code should look more like this...

```
highlight: function(element) {   
    $(element).addClass('error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) { 
    $(element).removeClass('error');
},
```

2)  Instead of all this...

```
var validator = $('#search-form').validate();
validator.element("#where");
```

just use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)...

```
$('#where').valid();
```

`.valid()` demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/LrS32/

Comment: Thanks for the background. I'm new to all this so this is very helpful!